# How to preselect dropdown given info from database to select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have this line and after it is submitted as a form, C7000 or C3000 gets stored as a string. For the edit page, I cannot get the stored value to be the preloaded option on the dropdown instead of "Select One". What am I doing wrong?

`= select_tag :enclosure_model, "<option>Select One</option><option>C7000</option><option>C3000</option>".html_safe, :disabled => false`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= select_tag :enclosure_model, helper.options_for_select([["select one", ""], ["c700"], "c700"], "c700"), :disabled => false %>
```

The above code will select c700

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I'm using HAML, and I'm not sure if that's what is causing the problem.